# node.js JS heap out of memory error - regardless of max-old-space-size setting

Tags: javascript, node.js, signal-processing

I am using a JS implementation of the Radix-4 FFT (this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fft.js). I'm analyzing sequences of 2^25 floats. The package works fine on the browser side with this size signal but on node.js it crashes:

> FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory
>
> [19262:0x559417f70870]    20352 ms: Scavenge 634.2 (656.1) -> 633.5
>   (671.6) MB, 65.3 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure

The process only reaches about 500-600mb before crashing, and changing max-old-space-size doesn't make any difference. It's possible that this fft implementation isn't great in terms of memory management, I just wanted to try to use this before going back to using some external script (e.g. scipy) to do the FFT. Either way I would like to know what wall I'm hitting here. It's probably a very simple one I'm not aware of..

Thanks

---

RESOLVED by changing from plain to typed arrays in fft implementation - the node process then uses more memory but the individual objects are smaller

Comment: Well if it's telling you it's out of memory, it's out of memory. How exactly are you storing those 2^25 "floats"?  JavaScript numbers are 8 bytes long, so that's actually  2^28 bytes, or 256 megabytes. You could be running into per-process limitations of your underlying operating system, or maybe (as you say) something is trying to make one or more copies or mappings from that array. There are lots of ways the code could consume more than expected memory.

Comment: What value are you using for `--max-old-space-size`?

Comment: I'm using Float32Array but the implementation just uses Array (apparently for backwards compatibility). And yes I believe that it's crashing when it creates one of these arrays as they are twice the fft and 64 bit, so 512mb. And that's just at the first copy. I've tried 16-32gb for max-old-space-size. The server has 64gb of memory.

Comment: OK right, well if you start off with the typed array, that's 128MB, and then it copies that to a plain array so that's another 256MB, and so on.

Comment: It still seems to be cutting out before reaching the actual memory limit. Could this be because of the size of the individual objects?

Comment: I changed the plain arrays in the implementation to typed arrays and it works but ultimately uses more memory, so it seems that the limitation was somehow related to the size of the individual objects.